# why is numpy's fft and fft2 not equal for 1D arrays?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

Can someone explain why applying numpy's fft and fft2 to the same 1D array yields different results?

```
 x = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 10)
 x = np.reshape(x, (10, 1))
 x = np.sin(x)
 f1 = np.fft.fft(x)
 f2 = np.fft.fft2(x)
 np.equal(f1,f2)
```

Theoretically, f1 should be equal to f2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer rewritten (sorry, the first one was a bit short):

The difference is, that [fft](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.fft.fft.html) takes other imnput arguments than [fft2](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.fft.fft2.htmlhttp://) (Fourier transformation (FT) in 2 dimensions).

If you `print(f1)` in your example you can see nicely, that all values are roughly 0. This should make you suspicious, as you Fourier transform the sinus.

What happend is, that the fft routine got a list of input aruments instead of an array, so it did the FT for each entry (1 element). This corresponds to a constant function and for that, math tells us: FT(const1)=const1. Four this reason you got the same output like input in fft. The fft2 routine you used properly.

Below you find you **example** in modified version, which illustrates the point:

```
import numpy as np
import copy
x1 = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 10)
x2 = np.reshape(x1, (10, 1))
x1 = np.sin(x1)
x2 = np.sin(x2)
f1 = np.fft.fft(x1)
f2 = np.fft.fft2(x2)

print('input arrays for fft and fft2:')
print(x1)
print(x2)
print('your old output of fft, which is exactly equal to the input x2')
print(np.fft.fft(x2))
print('Now we compare our results:')
for ii in range(0,len(x1)):
    print('f1:',f1[ii],'\tf2:',f2[ii,0])
print('and see, they agree')
```

**Output:**

```
input arrays for fft and fft2:

[  0.00000000e+00   6.42787610e-01   9.84807753e-01   8.66025404e-01

   3.42020143e-01  -3.42020143e-01  -8.66025404e-01  -9.84807753e-01

  -6.42787610e-01  -2.44929360e-16]

[[  0.00000000e+00]

 [  6.42787610e-01]

 [  9.84807753e-01]

 [  8.66025404e-01]

 [  3.42020143e-01]

 [ -3.42020143e-01]

 [ -8.66025404e-01]

 [ -9.84807753e-01]

 [ -6.42787610e-01]

 [ -2.44929360e-16]]

your old output of fft, which is exactly equal to the input x2

[[  0.00000000e+00+0.j]

 [  6.42787610e-01+0.j]

 [  9.84807753e-01+0.j]

 [  8.66025404e-01+0.j]

 [  3.42020143e-01+0.j]

 [ -3.42020143e-01+0.j]

 [ -8.66025404e-01+0.j]

 [ -9.84807753e-01+0.j]

 [ -6.42787610e-01+0.j]

 [ -2.44929360e-16+0.j]]

Now we compare our results:

f1: (-1.11022302463e-16+0j)     f2: (-1.11022302463e-16+0j)

f1: (1.42837120544-4.39607454395j)  f2: (1.42837120544-4.39607454395j)

f1: (-0.485917547994+0.668808127899j)   f2: (-0.485917547994+0.668808127899j)

f1: (-0.391335729991+0.284322050566j)   f2: (-0.391335729991+0.284322050566j)

f1: (-0.36913281032+0.119938520599j)    f2: (-0.36913281032+0.119938520599j)

f1: (-0.363970234266+1.55431223448e-15j)    f2: (-0.363970234266+1.55431223448e-15j)

f1: (-0.36913281032-0.119938520599j)    f2: (-0.36913281032-0.119938520599j)

f1: (-0.391335729991-0.284322050566j)   f2: (-0.391335729991-0.284322050566j)

f1: (-0.485917547994-0.668808127899j)   f2: (-0.485917547994-0.668808127899j)

f1: (1.42837120544+4.39607454395j)  f2: (1.42837120544+4.39607454395j)

and see, they agree
```

Some examples about fft2, you can find [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40593151/tutorial-tricks-and-banana-skins-for-discrete-fourier-transformation-ft-in-py)

Comment: but if the input is a one dimensional array, the output should be the same.

Comment: ok, good point. The difference is how fft and fft2 interpret the input -> see rewritten answer